# How does React/Redux app manage its history?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am new to React/Redux, and I was wondering how I can manage history.
I use the`BrowserRouter` from the `react-router-dom` package, and actually, it already seems to be handling it well.  I mean the back button just works.

But I want to understand why or if this is a proper way to handle history.   Can anyone be so kind to explain to me about this?

This is my `index.js`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/home';
import Contract from './components/contract';
import NotFound from './components/not-found';
import ScrollToTop from './components/scroll-to-top';

import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ScrollToTop>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/contract/:contractId" component={Contract}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404}/>
    </Switch>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser history management in your app is done by React Router. Redux can stay completely unaware of it. The way React Router is managing history is with [history package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) which is a small wrapper around window.location.history object (used for convenience and consistency between implementations). This object is passed as a prop to Route components so you can control history through it and it is also passed as a prop to Router component so react will recalculate DOM("rerender") when history object is changed (either by user action or code). For more info see [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)